# determining how often my app comes up in search

Tags: android, google-play

On the Google Play Developer console, I can access the User Acquisition Performance page which shows me the number of visits to my mobile app page.
To compare and determine (click-through-rate), I'd also like to know how often my app comes up in Google Play search queries.
Is it possible to get this statistics through Google's developer tools?

Comment: http://www.apptamin.com/blog/optimize-play-store-app/